# Elastic Cloud APM with Open Telemetry and Serilog

Tags: elasticsearch, serilog, open-telemetry, apm

I'm looking to use Elastic Cloud APM in my .NET application to send traces and metrics. I am using the [.NET Open Telemetry SDK](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore/README.md) to do this, not the Elastic .NET agents that Elastic provide.

Things are working well, I'm seeing my data in Observability in the Elastic console. I now want to correlate my logs to this APM data.

I'm currently using Serilog and the [Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch](https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch) sink.

Elastic provide some tooling (in conjunction with their own .NET agent) to enable correlation between the logs that are generated by the Serilog sink, and the traces that they generate, [see here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/dotnet/current/serilog.html).

I've tried to use this with the Open Telemetry SDK but am not having any luck, the logs don't show up in APM.

Is it possible to correlate logs that arrive in Elastic via the Serilog sink, with APM data that is generated by the .NET open telemetry SDK and sent to Elastic via their [Open Telemetry native support](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/guide/current/open-telemetry.html)?